# How can I get my horse back?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I was out in the world exploring and moved away from my horse a little and when I came back it was gone! I can't find it anywhere. Is there a recall feature, or tracking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the radial menu (LB for Xbox controllers, L2 for PS controllers) and summoning your horse should be the option at the bottom, it should have the icon for a horse's head.

Or, if you are playing on PC, the key is <kbd>=</kbd> or the last icon on the action bar, right hand side.

Comment: It's L1 for Playstation, not L2.